# NullPointerException after initializing object

Tags: java

When I initialize my arrays of StringBuilder like following, I receive a NullPointerException when calling it.

```
StringBuilder[] sb = new StringBuilder[2];
for(StringBuilder s : sb){
    s = new StringBuilder();
}
System.out.println(sb[0].toString());
```

However, after I change it to the following, the error message disappears. Can anyone explain what the differences are?

```
StringBuilder[] sb = new StringBuilder[2];
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    sb[i] = new StringBuilder();
}
System.out.println(sb[0].toString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand it better lets write the first loop with another way :

```
for(int i = 0; i < sb.length; i++) {
    StringBuilder temporary = sb[i]; 
    temporary = new StringBuilder();
}
```

this

```
for(StringBuilder s : sb)
```

equivalent to this :

```
for(int i = 0; i < sb.length; i++) 
    StringBuilder temporary = sb[i];
```

**Note** that initializing the **temporary** variable does not mean that you initialize the element in the array **sb[i]**, they are totally different.

Answer (score 1):

```
StringBuilder[] sb = new StringBuilder[2];
for(StringBuilder s : sb){
    s = new StringBuilder();
}
System.out.println(sb[0].toString());
```

sb[0] is null as you are not setting sb[0]=something anywhere

This line

```
for(StringBuilder s : sb){
```

Is doing: take every StringBuilder from `sb` and name is `s` variable. If you assign to s inside loop, you are simple swapping builder from array (null in that case) with new string builder, but you are not making an assignment.
So what you are doing, is changing value of `s` not `sb[x]`

Answer (score 1):

The `s` in your for-each loop is not synonymous with `sb[0]` on the first iteration (or any other iteration). It's a new variable that references whatever `sb[0]` is. This is like you did the following:

```
StringBuilder s = sb[0];
s = new StringBuilder(); // s is not null, but sb[0] is still null!
System.out.println(sb[0].toString); // NPE
```

Comment: *is not synonymous with sb[0] on the first iteration* on any iteration I would say.